# List comprehension in format string? (Python)

Tags: python, string, list, format, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list `datalist`, with `len(datalist) = 4`. Let's say I want each of the elements in the list to be represented in a string in this way:

```
s = "'{0}'::'{1}'::'{2}' '{3}'\n".format(datalist[0], datalist[1], datalist[2], datalist[3])
```

I don't like having to type `datalist[index]` so many times, and feel like there should be a more effective way. I tried:

```
s = "'{0}'::'{1}'::'{2}' '{3}'\n".format(datalist[i] for i in range(4))
```

But this doesn't work:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Does anybody know a functioning way to achieve this efficiently and concisely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, use [argument unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) with the "splat" operator `*`:

```
>>> s = "'{0}'::'{1}'::'{2}' '{3}'\n"
>>> datalist = ['foo','bar','baz','fizz']
>>> s.format(*datalist)
"'foo'::'bar'::'baz' 'fizz'\n"
>>>
```

#### Edit

As pointed out by @AChampion you can also just use indexing inside the format string itself:

```
>>> "'{0[0]}'::'{0[1]}'::'{0[2]}' '{0[3]}'\n".format(datalist)
"'foo'::'bar'::'baz' 'fizz'\n"
```

Comment: @Sandi yes, I've linked to the relevant documentation.

Comment: You can also just index in the format string `"'{0[0]}'::'{0[1]}'::'{0[2]}' '{0[3]}'\n".format(datalist)`

Comment: @Sandi read through the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Comment: Fot this method to work I'd have to know how many items the list has. What if I don't know beforehand how many items are in the list?

Comment: @kronosjt it depends on exactly what you are trying to accomplish. What sort of string are you trying to construct?

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension with enumerate() may be what you are looking for. You would not need to reference a list length with enumerate.

_>>enumerate(datalist) will return a tuple numbering the list items starting with default 0.

```
datalist = ['foo','bar','baz','fizz']    
[print('{}::{} '.format(index,data),end='') for index,data in enumerate(datalist)]
print()  #start new line
```

Output:

```
0::foo 1::bar 2::baz 3::fizz
```